# how represent sequence of month ends

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been long away from math so i am not very bright in the matter.

My goal is find a next month from date(y) that follows (Every x months on day 31).

Lets say we start from jan 2014, so sequence would be like 31,28,31,30,31 ...
And i want next month that repeats as x(lets say for example as third) but only interested in 31.
third from jan is april but there is no day 31 so we ignore that one and take next (july) which have 31 .

Can this be presented in some formula?

Comment: is modulus accepted?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to solve it in code eventually (i prefer not use loops for this)

Answer (score 0):

Months with 31 days are $1,3,5,7,8,10,12$. As I understand you start with month y and you want x month later. If the month y+x does not have 31 days you look at the next x month which has 31 days. 
You can formulate like this:
$$z = (y+nx \mod7), n=1,2,..$$
If $z$ odd or zero you are done.

Comment: Produced some random results and works perfectly :) thanks again. Have'to reintroduce myself back to math more, its fun to use.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you.

Comment: I was thinking is this possible without checking each month. in this case not going through each n until we have answer